# Empty array when calling tokenOfOwnerByIndex solidity

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

So, I've created a contract which has method which returns NFTs associated to the caller.

```
 function getOwnerByIndex(uint index) public view {
    tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address(msg.sender), index);
  }
```

Calling it from a script

```
  const NFTContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTContract");
  const nftContract = await NFTContract.deploy();

  await nftContract.deployed();

  console.log("Contract deployed to:", nftContract.address);
  await nftContract.mintToken();
  await nftContract.mintToken();
  const res = await nftContract.getBalanceOf();
  console.log(res) // BigNumber { value: "2" }
  const j = await nftContract.getOwnerByIndex(0);
  console.log(j) // []
}
```

It returns an empty array. I suppose index 0 should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the data.

I'm assuming you're using the OpenZeppelin [implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.4.1/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol#L37), which returns `uint256`. So your function should also return `uint256`.

```
// added `returns (uint256)`
function getOwnerByIndex(uint index) public view returns (uint256) {

    // added `return`
    return tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address(msg.sender), index);
}
```

---

However, the called OpenZeppelin function `tokenOfOwnerByIndex()` returns the token ID by the specified owner and index. Which is not what the name of your function `getOwnerByIndex()` suggests.

If you want to return the owner address by token index, you can use the `tokenByIndex()` to get the token ID, and then `ownerOf()` to get the owner of the token by its ID.

```
function getOwnerByIndex(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
    uint256 tokenId = tokenByIndex(index);
    address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
    return owner;
}
```